# Wampserver error to initialize

Tags: wampserver

I am trying to start wampserver and pulls me error. Try changing the port 80 by 8080 but did not work. Also change the port skype.
Anyone know what the problem is?

Error Log

```
2014-12-12 09:25:39 4460 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-12-12 09:25:40 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-12-12 09:25:48 4460 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1626213
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-12-12 09:25:49 4460 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.17'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

This is the last event in error log of apache:

```
[Tue Dec 09 06:46:54.906225 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5160:tid 292] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server. 
[Tue Dec 09 06:46:58.906453 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4620:tid 312] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited. 
[Tue Dec 09 06:47:00.838564 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5160:tid 292] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4620 exited successfully.
```

But today (15/12) nothing

Comment: Thats not an error, its just info that always appears in the `mysql error log`

Comment: What colour is your wampserver icon, the `W` in the system tray?

Comment: The colour of wampserver icon is orange

Comment: If the icon is Orange then one of the service has not started... as MYSQL seems to have started Ok, them Apache is not starting. Look at the Apache error log and if that is blank the Windows Event log, for error messages from Apache. When you know what the error is we can try fixing it.

Comment: This is the last event in error log of apache:  [Tue Dec 09 06:46:54.906225 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5160:tid 292] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Dec 09 06:46:58.906453 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4620:tid 312] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Dec 09 06:47:00.838564 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5160:tid 292] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4620 exited successfully. But today (15/12) nothing

Comment: Have you checked the `Windows Event Viewer` ??

Comment: What i have to check in Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Look for error messages from Apache.

Comment: That is the error:
Nombre de registro:Application
Origen:        Apache Service
Fecha:         16/12/2014 08:15:47 p.m.
Id. del evento:3299
Categoría de la tarea:Ninguno
Nivel:         Error
Palabras clave:Clásico
Usuario:       No disponible
Equipo:        LAUTARO-NB
Descripción:
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> Invalid address or port     .

Comment: And this:

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> AH00526: Syntax error on line 63 of D:/Programas/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf:     .

Comment: I found the problem, i have a jumpline in the file. Thanks very much